# Tanh function representation for conditional function

Tags: functional-analysis, discrete-mathematics, matlab

I have a condtion as
$$T(x)= 
\begin{cases}
-1 & \text{if }x <a  \\ 
0 & \text{if }a\le x \le b \\ 
1 & \text{if }x >b
\end{cases}
$$

I want to approximate the above condition as one formula using $tanh$ function . Could you help me please. This is my formula that I try

$T(x)=tanh(x-a).tanh(x-b)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$T(x)=\frac{tanh(x-a)+tanh(x-b)}{2} $$

With
$T(x)=\frac{tanh(p (x-a))+tanh(p (x-b))}{2} $
you can approximate your function as well as you want by making $p\rightarrow \infty $